# Call python code from c with cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm trying to call some python code from c and I'm trying to follow the [cython user guide](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html) on how to do that.

I've got a cython script, `modulename.pyx` that looks like this (taken from the user guide):

```
cdef public struct Bunny: # public type declaration
    int vorpalness

cdef public int spam # public variable declaration

cdef public void grail(Bunny b): # public function declaration
    print "Ready the holy hand grenade"
```

And I've got a c program, main.c, that looks like this (also from the guide):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "modulename.h"

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  initmodulename();
  struct Bunny b;
  grail(b);
  Py_Finalize();
}
```

I've tried to get this to compile in various ways with no luck. I can get the .pyx file compiled to c well enough with `cython modulename.pyx`, which produces `modulename.c` and `modulename.h`. The trouble comes when I want to compile and link those generated files along with my c program.

Here is one example of what I've been trying:

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c main.c modulename.h modulename.c
```

Which gave me these errors:

```
modulename.h:25:32: error: expected function body after function declarator
__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(void) grail(struct Bunny);
                           ^
modulename.h:27:31: error: expected function body after function declarator
__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(int) spam;
                          ^
modulename.h:32:1: error: unknown type name 'PyMODINIT_FUNC'
PyMODINIT_FUNC initmodulename(void);
^
3 errors generated.
```

I guess what I'm looking for is some guidance on getting the example to work or perhaps a pointer towards some example code that calls python code from c with cython.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I've figured out the issue. The problem was that I included `modulename.h` in the argument for the compiler. After I removed that, everyhing ran without any modification to either `main.c` or `modulename.pyx`. Also, not all those arguments were necessary for the compiler. The simplest way to compile the above code on my machine (Mac OS 10.9) is:

Compile:
`cc -c main.c modulename.c -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7`

Link:
`cc -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -ldl main.o modulename.o -o main`

Comment: Did you ever make any other insights about this problem?  I am trying to do something very similar, and I get the same exact errors, but I have no .h file being submitted to the compiler.

Comment: To fix this, I had to #include <Python.h> before I included my pyx's header file.